# hidden p elements not staying fixed in a hangman game

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner to javascript, css and html. Am creating a simple hangman game using these three languages. The problem I am having is that when I begin to turn to inline the display property of the p tags (containing the constituent letters of the word), the letters don't keep their position. For example, if the word 'clouds' is being guessed and the c and the o letters have been guessed correctly, the results appear as "c o _ _ _ _" instead of "c _ o _ _ s" . When the final letter has been guessed correctly, the word appears as normal but not before. That sort of takes the meaning out of hangman if I can't show the proper positions of the letters that haven't yet been selected but I can't seem to figure out the problem. The flow of my code is like this. I have four functions:

1. createAlphabets() that lists the grid of alphabets to be chosen.
2. selectWord() function that selects the word.
3. displayWord() function that creates p elements that are made to contain the letters of the above word selected, and their display property set as "none".
4. clickLetter() function that is called upon when any of the letter is clicked, and this letter is compared with the letters in the selected word, and the display property of the p element containing the letter is set to "inline".

Here is my code:

**HTML:**

```
    <body>
      <div id="container">
      <div id="hangman">
      <div id="stand"></div>
      <div id="face"></div>
      <div id="body"></div>
      <div id="left-arm"></div>
      <div id="right-arm"></div>
      <div id="left-leg"></div>
      <div id="right-leg"></div>

      </div>

    <div id="alphabet">

    </div>
    <div id="gameOver"><p>Game Over!<br>PS: I am not "actually" being hanged</p>
    </div>
<div id="beingGuessedWord"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
      #container {
         height:450px;
         width:600px;
         border:2px solid grey;
         border-radius:5px;
         background-color:hsla(115, 100%, 16%, 1);
         position:relative;  

         }

        #stand {

        background-image:url('http://i59.tinypic.com/sbll48.png');
        height:220px;
        width:200px;

       }

        #face {
        background-image:url('http://i59.tinypic.com/6dx0ee.png');
        height:60px;
        width:60px;
        position:relative;
        top:-175px;
        left:155px;
        visibility:hidden;  



        }

        #body {
        background-image:url('http://i61.tinypic.com/27ywcg.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        position:relative;
      height:50px;
      top:-175px;
      left:155px;
      visibility:hidden;  

      }

      #left-arm {
      background-image:url('http://i58.tinypic.com/2evvvac.png');
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      position:relative;
      height:70px;
      width:40px;
      top:-240px;
      left:150px;
      visibility:hidden;  


      }

     #right-arm{
     background-image:url('http://i58.tinypic.com/vfuhyp.png');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     position:relative;
     height:70px;
     width:40px;
     top:-300px;
     left:190px;
     visibility:hidden;  

     }

     #left-leg{
     background-image:url('http://i57.tinypic.com/t4u5na.png');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     position:relative;
     height:60px;
     width:60px;
     top:-335px;
     left:135px;
     visibility:hidden;  

     }

    #right-leg{
    background-image:url('http://i61.tinypic.com/2dqplzb.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    height:50px;
    width:60px;
    top:-385px;
    left:180px;
    visibility:hidden; 

    }

    #alphabet {
    height:100px;
    width:250px;
    position:relative;
    top:-450px;
    left:300px;
    text-align:center;

    }

    #alphabet a {
    font-size:20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin:5px;
    font-family: 'Crafty Girls', cursive;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:grey;

    }

    #beingGuessedWord {
    height:70px;
    width:300px;
    position:relative;
    top:-500px;
    left:80px;
    padding-top:50px;

    }

   .letterp {
    border:2px solid black;
    font-family:"Crafty Girls", cursive;
    font-size:20px;
    margin:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:5px;
    border-radius:5px;


    }

   #dash {
   padding:5px;
   margin:5px;
   font-weight:bold;
   font-family:serif;

  }

  #gameOver {
  border:3px solid grey;

  font-family:'Crafty Girls', cursive;
  font-size:15px;
  font-weight:bold;
  position:relative;
  top:-670px;
  left:300px;
  height:70px;
  width:280px;   
  border-radius:5px;
  text-align:center;   
  visibility:hidden;      

 }
```

**JavaScript**

```
var totalIncorrectClicks = 0;//Global variable

var clickLetter = function() {


  var clickedLetter = document.getElementById(this.id);  
  var word = clickedLetter.getAttribute("data-word");


    var compareSuccess = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {

      if (word[i] == clickedLetter.innerHTML) 
      {

          var pId = "id" + word[i];

          var pNode = document.getElementById(pId);
          pNode.style.display = "inline";
          compareSuccess = true;

      }

    }

    if (compareSuccess == false)
    {
        totalIncorrectClicks++;
    }

    if (compareSuccess == false && totalIncorrectClicks <=7)
    {
        if (totalIncorrectClicks == 1)
        {
        var face = document.getElementById('face');
        face.style.visibility = "visible";
        }

         if (totalIncorrectClicks == 2)
        {
        var body = document.getElementById('body');
        body.style.visibility = "visible";
        }

         if (totalIncorrectClicks == 3)
        {
        var leftArm = document.getElementById('left-arm');
        leftArm.style.visibility = "visible";
        }

         if (totalIncorrectClicks == 4)
        {
        var rightArm = document.getElementById('right-arm');
        rightArm.style.visibility = "visible";
        }

         if (totalIncorrectClicks == 5)
        {
        var leftLeg = document.getElementById('left-leg');
        leftLeg.style.visibility = "visible";
        }

         if (totalIncorrectClicks == 6)
        {
        var rightLeg = document.getElementById('right-leg');
        rightLeg.style.visibility = "visible";
        }

        if (totalIncorrectClicks == 7)
        {
            var gameOver = document.getElementById('gameOver');
            gameOver.style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }


}

var createAlphabets = function () {
  var alphabets = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

for (var i = 0; i < alphabets.length; i++)
  {
    var anchorNode = document.createElement('a');
    var idanch = "id" + (i+1);


    anchorNode.setAttribute('id', idanch);


    anchorNode.innerHTML = alphabets[i];

    anchorNode.setAttribute('href', "#");


    var alphaDiv = document.getElementById('alphabet')

    alphaDiv.appendChild(anchorNode);

    if (i == 11 || i == 22)
      {
        alphaDiv.innerHTML = alphaDiv.innerHTML + "<br>"

      }


  }
}

var selectWord = function() {

  var wordArray = ["air", "clouds", "sun"];
  var randomWord = wordArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordArray.length)];
  var splitRandomWord = randomWord.split('');

  return splitRandomWord;

}


var displayWord  = function(word) {


  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {


    var dispWordDiv = document.getElementById('beingGuessedWord');


    var pNode = document.createElement('p');

    pNode.innerHTML = word[i];
    var id = "id" + word[i];
    pNode.setAttribute('id', id);
    pNode.setAttribute('class', "letterp");  
      pNode.style.display = "none";

    dispWordDiv.appendChild(pNode);

  }

  var dispWordDiv  = document.getElementById('beingGuessedWord');
  dispWordDiv.innerHTML = dispWordDiv.innerHTML + "<br>"; 

  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
      var dispWordDiv  = document.getElementById('beingGuessedWord');
      var empty = document.createElement('p');
      empty.setAttribute('id', 'dash');
      empty.innerHTML = "___";
      empty.style.display = "inline";



    dispWordDiv.appendChild(empty);
  }
  }

  var word = selectWord();
  createAlphabets();
  displayWord(word);
  for (var i = 0; i < 27 ; i++) {
  var id = "id" + ( i + 1 );
  var anchor  = document.getElementById(id);
  anchor.setAttribute('data-word', word);    
  anchor.onclick = clickLetter;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h_i_r_a/5rtwed1d/9/

Thanks!

Comment: Your life as a web developer will be much easier if you learn to use developer tools for the browser of your choice. When I looked using Firebug, it was very obvious what is happening. Give it a try! it helps immensely with tweaking layout, debugging JavaScript, etc.

Comment: I have recently started using them, and I did try to see what was wrong but it wasn't very obvious to me, pretty much a beginner I guess :) The p elements appeared in their normal order, so I supposed just turning on the display option to inline should work fine, how did you figure out through it ?

Comment: Looking at the HTML, when a letter was clicked, I saw the p element for that letter become visible but in the wrong position visually. It was obvious to me that the preceding p elements were not in the flow. I guess it was experience that made that obvious, but the tool showed it to me. BTW, your algorithm will have problems if you get a word that that a repeated letter in it. Since you are using the letter to create the element's ID, you will get duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the repeated letters problem. After you pointed out, I have been trying for some time to solve this, and I can't figure out. Guess I'll post in a separate thread for help. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is about your way. You make p's style 'display:none' in order to make it invisible. You should use 'visibility:hidden' instead. If you make its display none, then it will act like it doesn't exist. But if you use visibility property then, it will act like it exists but invisible

http://jsfiddle.net/5rtwed1d/11/

```
if (word[i] == clickedLetter.innerHTML) 
  {

      var pId = "id" + word[i];

      var pNode = document.getElementById(pId);
      pNode.style.visibility = "visible";
      compareSuccess = true;

  }
```

Comment: Aha! I actually did try this, but I wasn't setting display to inline alongside as well (like you did) when I used visibility which made all the letters appear in block. Thanks, this works!

Answer (score 1):

well, when you reveal a hidden element, the browser will show this on the most left available edge of the page... (cause the default orientation is left side)

if I were you I would create a table like this

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td> 1st hidden char </td>
  <td> 2nd hidden char </td>
  ...
  <td> Nth hidden char</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td> 1st underline _ </td>
  <td> 2nd underline _ </td>
  ...
  <td> Nth underline _ </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

(even dynamically for each word)
so when you reveal a hidden element, it will show up right at its place :)

hope it helps

Comment: thanks! Sounds like a very neat way to do it, I am gonna try this alternatively as well!